# Is it necessary to translate the direction character in a latitude/longitude?

Tags: gps, translation

Possibly a subjective question this (although I hope not).  I am translating an application into European Spanish.  This application provides on-screen latitude and longitude display.

When displaying the direction of a given longitude in English, an example might be:

```
10° W 10' 2.42"
```

However, the word **West** in Spanish translates to **Oeste**.  Is it convention to leave the character in the longitude in English or translate it to Spanish, like so:

```
10° O 10' 2.42"
```

Personally I feel that as a maritime standard it needs no translations, but if anyone can point me to an example where this is not true that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most languages do translate them – that's the case with Finnish, Swedish and German, at least. I'd still keep their English names if it was really a maritime software, since most people on special fields are most accustomed to see the English characters denoting the hemispheres. Actually, some translations might also cause confusion if presented to an unfamiliar user, eg. "south" in Finnish would be shortened as E, which would be shortened version for east in the original version.

Other option worth considering would be using signed numbers, ie. -10° for 10° W. That's quite widely used and very unambiguous. If you aren't running out of space, I'd use the real names of the hemispheres instead of abbreviations, to stay on the safe side.